# How to get the percentage of width with respect to cursor position

Tags: c#

Working with zoom and I found it necessary to set the scroll bar position based on width with respect to the cursor position. How would I be able to accomplish this?

For example if the cursor is at position 300 x-axis for the control and the control is 600 in width, how would I be able to automatically translate this into percentage to use on panel scroll bars?

Comment: Sounds interesting. What have you tried so far? Show us your attempt/code and we'll help you with a specific question or problem.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because everything I thought of ended up logically failing.

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=c-sharp+set+scrollbar+position and https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=c-sharp+get+cursor+position